# Gradle is not building

Tags: android, gradle

Hi I'm Adding authentication system Google Apps.
I've done all the steps but when I compile the application to a treatment error.
Error text:

Gradle 'signin' project refresh failed. Error:Connection timed out: connect. If you are behind an HTTP proxy, please configure the proxy settings either in IDE or Gradle.

I'd be glad if you help me.

Comment: if you are in countries that have restricted access to google sources use vpn or bypass applications

Answer (score 0):

This might be the issue of the delay response  because according to the error log reply from the API is not coming in stipulated time. You might need to increase the timeout time

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have not set the proxy yet.

First check your internet proxy settings copy the proxy settings like proxy host and port no. and go to your "gradle.properties" file in project and paste it like this

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost="copied proxy host"
systemProp.http.proxyPort="copied proxy port"

systemProp.https.proxyHost="copied proxy host"
systemProp.https.proxyPort="copied proxy port"
```

Generally people paste the system prop for http but forget for https so please paste both.